# Is it possible to retain newlines when using CDATA in BIML Variables?

Tags: biml

I have some SQL in a variable that I want to use in a BIML template. (Originally I was getting the SQL from a C# variable, but that doesn't seem to be relevant) I'm using BIML like this:

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <OleDbConnection Name="Source" ConnectionString="Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=localhost\dev2017;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=tempdb;" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="SO_51407483" ConstraintMode="Linear">
            <Variables>
                <Variable Name="querySql" DataType="String" IncludeInDebugDump="Exclude" EvaluateAsExpression="true">
                  <![CDATA["SELECT --This is a comment
1 AS Col1"]]>
                </Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT Demo">
                    <Transformations>
                        <OleDbSource Name="OLESRC query" ConnectionName="Source">
                            <VariableInput VariableName="User.querySql" />
                        </OleDbSource>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

The issue I have is that when the file is compiled the line breaks in querySql appear to be stripped out, **but only during the validation step of the compilation**. This means that anything after the first comment in querySql becomes part of the comment and BIML's validation fails.

The error message is:

> Node OLESRC query: Could not execute Query on Connection Source:
>
> SELECT --This is a comment1 AS Col1
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'

If I change querySql to use the /* */ style of comment the validation passes. If I then open the generated dtsx and look at the variable in SSIS **the line breaks are there again**.

Is there a way around this without having to use /* */ everywhere?

**Experiments**

This doesn't compile:

```
<Variable Name="querySql" DataType="String" IncludeInDebugDump="Exclude" EvaluateAsExpression="true">
    "SELECT --This is a comment
1 AS Col1"
</Variable>
```

This compiles, and the resulting dtsx variable ends up with **one** line break

```
<Variable Name="querySql" DataType="String" IncludeInDebugDump="Exclude" EvaluateAsExpression="true">
    "SELECT /*This is a comment*/
1 AS Col1"
</Variable>
```

This compiles, and the resulting dtsx variable ends up with **two** line breaks

```
<Variable Name="querySql" DataType="String" IncludeInDebugDump="Exclude" EvaluateAsExpression="true">
    "SELECT --This is a comment&#xD;&#xA;
1 AS Col1"
</Variable>
```

I've raised this with Variagence: https://github.com/varigence/BimlPit/issues/82

Comment: My reproduction used BimlExpress. The expanded Biml contained crlf. The emitted SSIS package preserved then as well. Do you experience a different behaviour?

Comment: Yes, I get a compile error when the compiler tries to verify that the SQL is valid. I'm away for a few days, but will try to cut my case down to a minimal one when I'm back.

Comment: When you're back, under BimlExpress menu option, use "Abount BimlExpress" and what version/build are you on? I have Varigence BimlExpress 5.0 (32-bit)
Build 5.0.62720.0 which is new as of beginning of July 2018

Comment: My version is: Varigence BimlExpress 5.0 (32-bit)
Build 5.0.63025.0
Features and Bundles: No features or bundles have been authorized
Plugins: No plugins have been loaded

Comment: @billinkc So I can't get the initial failure to occur any more. It is most likely that I mis-typed the question originally. However, the new complete file above does fail to compile in the same way.

Comment: I believe this is because you are storing your SQL script as a variable, which is removing the `newline` characters rather than the Biml itself.  If you are using variables you will have to use the `/*...*/` syntax as a workaround.

Comment: @iamdave Hi, I'm not sure I understand. SSIS variables don't strip out line breaks as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

As a minimal repro, I'm getting the carriage return/line feeds preserved.

I declare my query variable and then use it in both an Execute SQL Task and a Dataflow's OLEDB Source.

The Execute SQL Task doesn't look like it preserves the CR/LF until you click the ellipses but then the popup correctly displays the code.

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
<#
string query = @"--This is a comment
SELECT 1 AS Col1";
#>
    <Connections>
        <OleDbConnection Name="Source" ConnectionString="Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=localhost\dev2017;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=tempdb;" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="SO_51407483" ConstraintMode="Linear">
            <Tasks>
                <ExecuteSQL Name="SQL Test Task" ConnectionName="Source">
                    <DirectInput><![CDATA[<#=query#>]]></DirectInput>
                </ExecuteSQL>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT Demo">
                    <Transformations>
                        <OleDbSource Name="OLESRC query" ConnectionName="Source">
                            <DirectInput><![CDATA[<#=query#>]]></DirectInput>
                        </OleDbSource>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think I may have been unclear in my question. I've updated it with more details.